# cocos2d subclassing sprite to handle touch?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, touch, sprite, layer, cocos2d-x

I'm new to the cocos2d(-x) world.

I'd like to detect a touch to a sprite, and tutorials/examples seem to suggest using layer to detect touch and find the approapriate  sprite with bounding box.

Is subclassing sprite to allow touch detection generally a bad idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is better and much more clear to handle touches in one place. but i think, no one can bar you to do this

Comment: Why do you say it's better to handle touches in one place?

Comment: is this is just a sprite, it is no need to make touch handler from it. for my mind, it is not clear enough to understand when reading code.

Comment: This technically answers the question so I'll upvote this as well. For anyone more concerned with how to do this rather than if you should or should not please scroll down and check out m.ding's reply.

Comment: tanyanzhi's answer works well with recent Cocos2D-x like 3.5.

Answer (score 14):

*Note: This answer might be outdated. I answered this at 2012.*

It is not a bad idea. Here is how I do it:

header file:

```
#include "cocos2d.h"
using namespace cocos2d;
class TouchableSprite : public cocos2d::CCSprite, public CCTargetedTouchDelegate {
    public:
    virtual void onEnter();
    virtual void onExit();
    virtual bool ccTouchBegan(CCTouch* touch, CCEvent* event);
    virtual void ccTouchMoved(CCTouch* touch, CCEvent* event);
    virtual void ccTouchEnded(CCTouch* touch, CCEvent* event);
};
```

cpp file:

```
#include "TouchableSprite.h"
void TouchableSprite::onEnter(){
    // before 2.0:
    // CCTouchDispatcher::sharedDispatcher()->addTargetedDelegate(this, 0, true);

    // since 2.0: 
    CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()->addTargetedDelegate(this, 0, true);
    CCSprite::onEnter();
}
void TouchableSprite::onExit(){
    // before 2.0:
    // CCTouchDispatcher::sharedDispatcher()->removeDelegate(this);

    // since 2.0:
    CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()->removeDelegate(this);
    CCSprite::onExit();
}
bool TouchableSprite::ccTouchBegan(CCTouch* touch, CCEvent* event){
    //do whatever you want here
    return true;
}
void TouchableSprite::ccTouchMoved(CCTouch* touch, CCEvent* event){
    //do what you want
}
void TouchableSprite::ccTouchEnded(CCTouch* touch, CCEvent* event){
    //do your job here
}
```

Comment: Agreed. There are great reasons to do this such as creating your own dialog. This is the best answer here.

Comment: @JayGajjar in ccTouchMoved, using `touch->getLocation()` and `touch->getProviousLocation()` to calculate the moving vector. Then call `this->setPosition(ccpAdd(this->getPosition(),moving_vector));`

Comment: @m.ding hey can you please tell me were i can get full code on how to drag or move the ccsprite & b2body ? Because i am not able to move the ccsprite

Comment: @JayGajjar Sorry I didn't do it before. but there are some sample projects on the cocos2d-x website which might help (I am not sure)

Comment: The Sprite touch event fires no matter where I touch the screen , can you please help ... I have used this code

Comment: this is just dont work any more in cocos2d-x , i never made it to work
see this : 
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/33443?r=33801
all saying that it needs to be on the " controller " object not in the  
sprites them self

Comment: I tried to use this solution but I still can't call the super method CCSprite::create()

Answer (score 6):

In cocos2d-x 3.0 alpha you can try this:

```
auto listener = EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();

listener->setSwallowTouches(true);

listener->onTouchBegan = [&](Touch* touch, Event* event){

    if (this->getBoundingBox().containsPoint(this->convertTouchToNodeSpace(touch))) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;

};

Director::getInstance()->getEventDispatcher()->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(listener, this);
```

Comment: Coming from Java world, I wonder what the [&] in line:
  listener->onTouchBegan = [&](Touch* touch, Event* event){
mean?

Comment: @AriR.Fikri Not sure, but it's a reference to `this` I think?

Answer (score -3):

You do not need to subclass sprites to detect touch.

Here, Follow this [LINK](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials) its a nice place to get started with Cocos2d