# Cocos2d-x and handling touch events

Tags: c++, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, multi-touch

I have my sprites on screen and I have a vector that stores each sprite.

Can a CCSprite* handle a touch event? Or just the CCLayer*?

What is the best way to decide what sprite was touched? Should I store the coordinates of where the sprite is (in the sprite class) and when I get the event, see if where the user touched is where the sprite is by looking through the vector and getting each sprites current coordinates?
UPDATE: I subclass CCSprite:

`class Field : public cocos2d::CCSprite, public cocos2d::CCTargetedTouchDelegate`

and I implement functions:

```
    cocos2d::CCRect rect();

    virtual void onEnter();
    virtual void onExit();

    bool containsTouchLocation(cocos2d::CCTouch* touch);
    virtual bool ccTouchBegan(cocos2d::CCTouch* touch, cocos2d::CCEvent* event);
    virtual void ccTouchMoved(cocos2d::CCTouch* touch, cocos2d::CCEvent* event);
    virtual void ccTouchEnded(cocos2d::CCTouch* touch, cocos2d::CCEvent* event);

    virtual void touchDelegateRetain();
    virtual void touchDelegateRelease();
```

I put CCLOG statements in each one and I dont hit them!

When I touch the CCLayer this sprite is on though I do hit those in the class that implements the Layer and puts these sprites on the layer.

UPDATE: The code I have been trying:

```
Field* Field::createWithLocation(cocos2d::CCPoint p)
{
    Field* f = new Field();
    f->autorelease();
    f->initWithLocation(p);
    return f;
}

void Field::initWithLocation(cocos2d::CCPoint p)
{
    setFieldCenterPoint(p);
    setFieldGraphicName(FIELD::fieldIconFileName);

    setFieldSprite(cocos2d::CCSprite::create(getFieldGraphicName().c_str()));
    getFieldSprite()->setPosition(ccp(getFieldCenterPoint().x, getFieldCenterPoint().y));

    setFieldSize(getFieldSprite()->getContentSize());
}

cocos2d::CCRect Field::rect()
{
    cocos2d::CCSize s = getFieldSprite()->getTexture()->getContentSize();
    return cocos2d::CCRectMake(-s.width / 2, -s.height / 2, s.width, s.height);
}

void Field::onEnter()
{
    CCLOG("In onEnter");
    cocos2d::CCDirector* pDirector = cocos2d::CCDirector::sharedDirector();
    pDirector->getTouchDispatcher()->addTargetedDelegate(this, 0, true);
    //_dir->Instance()->getDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()->addTargetedDelegate(this, 0, true);
    cocos2d::CCSprite::onEnter();
}

void Field::onExit()
{
    CCLOG("In onExit");
    cocos2d::CCDirector* pDirector = cocos2d::CCDirector::sharedDirector();
    pDirector->getTouchDispatcher()->removeDelegate(this);
    //_dir->Instance()->getDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()->removeDelegate(this);
    cocos2d::CCSprite::onExit();
}

bool Field::containsTouchLocation(cocos2d::CCTouch* touch)
{
    return rect().containsPoint(convertTouchToNodeSpaceAR(touch));
}

bool Field::ccTouchBegan(cocos2d::CCTouch* touch, cocos2d::CCEvent* event)
{
    CCLOG("In ccTouchBegan");

    return true;
}

void Field::ccTouchMoved(cocos2d::CCTouch* touch, cocos2d::CCEvent* event)
{
    CCLOG("In ccTouchMoved");
}

void Field::ccTouchEnded(cocos2d::CCTouch* touch, cocos2d::CCEvent* event)
{
     CCLOG("In ccTouchEnded");
}

void Field::touchDelegateRetain()
{
    this->retain();
}

void Field::touchDelegateRelease()
{
    this->release();
}
```

Comment: @m.ding, I've already tried the solution mentioned in link you have given, but in my case its of no use.

Comment: @Rv15 - what are you sub-classing?

Answer (score 0):

I have answered this before.

Please go to [cocos2d subclassing sprite to handle touch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354689/cocos2d-subclassing-sprite-to-handle-touch/11387423#11387423) to find the details.

Comment: I think I am doing all of this already. Let me look over your previous answer carefully. I did find out that if I capture the touch even on my layer and run through my vector then I can get it to work. I just wanted each sprite to answer for itself.

Comment: @you missed `CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()->addTargetedDelegate(this, 0, true);` in `onEnter()`. if you didn't register the sprite on TouchDispatcher, how can your sprite get the touch? and don't forget to unregister in `onExit()`

Comment: @Jason the register process is like someone says "Hi, Jason, if the system got a touch event happens, please pass it to me and don't give it to anyone else".

Comment: I have the getTouchDispatcher() lines you mention above in my onEnter()

Comment: @Jason Can you post the code of the create() function for your `Field` class and where did you create the `Field` object and use it? and make sure `addTargetedDelegate(this, INT_MIN, true)` priority you set is higher than any other Object.

Comment: sure, see update above for part of the .cpp. I instantiate it like in code where I need it: `Field* f1 = Field::createWithLocation(ccp( p.x, p.y));`
    `addChild(f1->getFieldSprite(), 2);`

Comment: @Jason something possibly you can do: 1. when adding child, try to add f1 instead of f1's sprite, there is possibility that the sprite itself is retained byt the field is autoreleased. 2. try to change the `addTargetedDelegate(this, INT_MIN, true)` using INT_MIN

Comment: If I add `f1` like: `addChild(f1, 2);` instead of f1 sprite I hit an assertion of : `
    CCAssert(!m_pobBatchNode, "If CCSprite is being rendered by CCSpriteBatchNode, CCSprite#draw SHOULD NOT be called");` in CCSprite::draw

Comment: using `INT_MIN` instead of `0` throws an exception in `
CCRect CCNode::boundingBox()
{
    CCRect rect = CCRectMake(0, 0, m_obContentSize.width, m_obContentSize.height);
    return CCRectApplyAffineTransform(rect, nodeToParentTransform());
}
`

Comment: @Jason it looks like there are more problems than I expected. cos from your code I am not sure if you want to use object composition or inheritance. do you want your field `contains` a sprite or your field `is a` sprite?

Comment: `Field` subclasses `CCSprite*` like: `class Field : public cocos2d::CCSprite, public cocos2d::CCTargetedTouchDelegate`

Comment: I am realizing that `Field` is technically a `CCSprite*` and i am also creating a `CCSprite*` when init the Field object. My thought here was that I would be doing other things with `Field` like putting other sprites on it and if I could keep the logic andUI a bit separate it might mak that easier. Maybe I should make `Field` a plain object and not extend `CCSprite*` since I create one also

Comment: @Jason That's what I guess as well. maybe a subclass of CCNode will be enough. coz you are using composition more than inheritance

Comment: Ho man i trying to find the right answer without no answer , it seams like you can't do it from within the object itself only form outside
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/33443?r=33801

Comment: The general consensus is to include a working example in answers.